# The meaning of $*$ in regular expressions

Tags: turing-machines, regular-expressions

I'm designing a Turing machine that decides a language denoted by a regular expression. Let's say this expression is $a^*bbc^*$. Does this machine accept the string $bb$ since $a^*$ and $c^*$ can have zero instances or more?

Comment: Yes, $a^*bbc^*$ matches $bb$.

Comment: The meaning of * is covered in your textbook and in any online reference such as wikipedia. You're expected to do at least basic research before asking here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the word $bb$ in the language generated by the regular expression $a^*bbc^*$, because, as you say, $a^*$ and $c^*$ generate also the empty word. So if you are building a Turing machine that accepts this language, it should also accept the string $bb$.